# Mama Murphy won't switch settlements

Tags: fallout-4

Mama Murphy is currently in sanctuary and I want her in the red rocket. In build mode, when I look at her it doesn't show anything different, so I can't command or move her. When I talk to her, she says "Mama Murphy's as good as her word kid. No more Chem's, and no more sight either." I tried fiddling with her chair but that did nothing, now she doesn't even want to sit in it. If anyone knows a way to move mama Murphy I'd love to know.

Comment: AFAIK, she is locked to Sanctuary. There are other settlers like that - Sturges, Marcy and her husband, that guy at another settlement, whose sword was stolen, etc. Sort of unique named characters that can't be relocated.

Comment: @Headcrab You are right. Original settlers of any settlement that was already inhabited prior to the player meeting them will never leave their settlement. This includes special ones such as The Slog or Sanctuary as well as generic settlers such as in Oberland Station

Comment: I could move everyone else in sanctuary, like the ones you mentioned @Headcrab "Sturges, Marcy and her husband," Mama murphy is speacial for some reason. I moved them in build mode by looking at them and hitting x on xbox and square on play station and R on pc.

Comment: @CrazyOlHoboJoe My bad, I should've checked about Sturges, Marcy etc. before mentioning them as non-movable settlers. Still, such settlers do exist. And Mama Murphy is even more special - for example, you can't wear her garb, which is a real shame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't*. Character is essential for Sanctuary location. Especially dialogues are related to Sanctuary.

When you meet her in Sanctuary, she says:

> "You're tied to this place, kid. Your energy"

That will be little off if you move **Mama Murphy** somewhere else like [Graygarden](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Graygarden) where player never was before war.

<sup>*Maybe there is workaround with mods/console. But not standard way to do this.</sup>